# Asus Router web admin site forces manually typing password (no copy paste)

Tags: firefox, router, security, passwords, copy-paste

The Asus Router RT-N66U Router's admin website changed a few versions back to prevent pasting into the login password field.

Firmware 3.0.0.4.378_6117 (Latest as of 9/12/2015)

Given I use a randomly generated password it is annoying to type manually.  Asus has 16 character password limit.  Browser password storage is not desired.  Autotype is not a good solution since the password manager is in an isolated non-networked VM.

I saw [SSH access is possible](https://superuser.com/questions/811034/asus-rt-n66u-enable-ssh-access), so perhaps a trick can send the GUI over SSH.  Perhaps the username/password be passed in through a URL although post login firefox history does not show a page with the URL clue.

**How can I make password entry easier?**

Comment: https://twitter.com/atxryan/status/618510122000580608

Comment: @DragonLord Agreed it is just downright counter productive for companies to do this

Comment: A note: this is no longer the case. Current Asus router firmware allow pasting the password in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple different things you can try, although both of which involve your browser.

1. If the form page uses JavaScript, it may be listening for the `onPaste` event. You can temporarily disable JavaScript on that page with an extension like [JS Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-switch/) to bypass this.
2. The form page may be communicating with Firefox directly to disallow pasting on that page. You can disable a relevant setting hidden setting (`dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`) and restart Firefox. Here's [a tutorial on how to change this](http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/re-enable-copy-paste-annoying-sites-block-0155910/).

Comment: #1 Tried noscript which sounds like it may do the same by blocking javascript.  No luck.  #2 Worked, Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I finally got tired of this and just googled it and landed here. These answers didn't help but got me thinking. Instead of going through all of the fixes which will take more time to find out how to do them,(which I dis), just log into the router with a simple 8 character pa$$word and then immediately change it from Administration menu, system tab to a strong one with copy paste which will now work as expected. This works with RT-AC66U_B1 F/W:3.0.0.4.384_20308.
Regards, K

Comment: Current Asus router firmware allow pasting.